# Visual FoxPro driver for 64 bit Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, visual-foxpro

I've installed Visual FoxPro driver from this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14839) on my 64 Bit Windows 7 Home Premium OS and tried to register vfpoledb.dll using REGSVR32. I could able to register this dll but when run my application which accesses VFP database is throwing the following error:
**System.InvalidOperationException: The 'VFPOLEDB.1' provider is not registered on the local machine.**

The same application is working fine in 32 bit Windows 7 Home Premium OS without any issues. I have googled for 64 bit VFP driver and found out that there are no VFP drivers for 64 bit OS from this  [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/307744/visual-foxpro-64-bit-ole-db-driver). Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have found out that there is no 64 bit VFP Driver for 64 bit OS. All we have to do is to change the build option in project properties and set the Platform Target to X86 instead of Any CPU. Build the application for X86. Please refer to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/visualfoxprogeneral/thread/4abede88-b844-4bb5-a8b4-d49169eee8dd/) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit late, but may help somebody else:) You can use [Advantage OLE DB Provider for Windows 64-bit](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=20&Release=19&Product=15&Platform=14), which works like VFPOLEDB. Example in python:

```
conn = win32com.client.Dispatch('ADODB.Connection')
dsn = 'Provider=Advantage OLE DB Provider;Data Source=%s; ServerType=ADS_LOCAL_SERVER; TableType=ADS_VFP;' % folder
conn.Open(dsn)
cmd.CommandText = 'ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN area NOT NULL'
cmd.Execute()
```

Comment: I am using Advantage OLE DB Provider for Windows 64-bit because VFPOLEDB is not available in 64-bit mode. In my ASP.NET MVC application (programmed using C#) I have set below connection string: string conString = @"Provider=Advantage OLE DB Provider;Data Source=" + dbfFilePath + ";ServerType=ADS_LOCAL_SERVER;TableType=ADS_VFP;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;"; My dbfFilePath is something like "C:\MyApp\Data\MyDbfFile.dbf" and when I execute Open command I get error 7077: The Advantage Data Dictionary cannot be openend. axServerConnect AdsConnect. Do you know why?

Comment: @Ralph, try "C:\MyApp\Data" instead, I think there should be a folder path.

Answer (score -1):

[A blog post by Eric Selje](https://web.archive.org/web/20140908132856/http://saltydogllc.com/?p=356), of Salty Dog Solutions, describes how to run the 32-bit drivers on 64-bit Windows. (You must set them up in the 32-bit ODBC Administrator.)

> 1. Visual FoxPro, a 32-bit application, runs just fine on 64-bit machines.
> 2. Visual FoxPro cannot use 64-bit ODBC drivers however.
> 3. You can use 32-bit ODBC drivers on 64-bit Windows, but you must set them up in the 32-bit ODBC Administrator. This is not the one that’s
>    going to come up if you go through Control Panel. To invoke it, run
>    C:\Windows\SysWow64\odbcad32.exe and add your DSNs there.
> 4. Do not just Start, Run, ODBCAd32.exe, as it will not bring up the right one.
> 5. The 32-bit drivers for SQL Server come with Windows 7 x64, so you don’t have to download them.

Comment: You're talking about ODBC drivers; he's using an oledb driver as far as I can tell. Two different things.