# 64 bit java read write *dbf

Tags: java, odbc, 64-bit, dbf

Heya all,

I am having some issues and maybe someone has an answer for me!

I am trying to read write some *DBF table from a java application. I have found this code :

```
try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String connString="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver *.dbf)};DefaultDir=C:\\test";//DefaultDir indicates the location of the db
            Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection(connString);
            String sql="SELECT * FROM table_name where condition";// usual sql query
            Statement stmt=connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while(resultSet.next())
            {
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This code is working fine with a 32-bit version of windows but when I try on 64 bit, it gives me the error :

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

I have looked it up and the best answer found was about something to do with playing with the DNs in system32 or sysWOW64 but I wasent able to get threw it or my understanding was no good enough....

Here is the link with that answer:

[SO answer that I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895823/the-specified-dsn-contains-an-architecture-mismatch-between-the-driver-and-appli/12537390#12537390)

thanks in advance...

Comment: 64 bit version here http://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: Already tried that option, unfortunately, didn't fix it..

Comment: FoxPro(dbf) is only 32 bit and there are no 64 bit drivers from microsoft. The link above is for Access and not dbf. Further info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543670/visual-foxpro-driver-for-64-bit-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it uninstalling the 64-bit version of the JDK 6 and installing instead the 32-bit one.
Thus my application started back to work fine with queries/updates on my *.DBF files :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thats right, installing x86 version works